# Take multiple ACF user fields and combine them into one

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have some ACF user fields on posts where users can be selected, I would like to take those fields and combine them into another field. So basically the users in field 1 and field 2 show up in field 3. Here is what I have tried so far. The return format for the fields is user array.

```
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 10 );
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {
    // Get value of field 1
    $value1 = get_field( 'contractor', $post_id );
    // Get value of field 2 
    $value2 = get_field( 'architect', $post_id );

    update_field( 'project_user_select', $value1 . $value2, $post_id );
}
```

Comment: `update_field` is outside of your function.

Comment: Thanks, I adjusted that. It still won’t show the selections in the other two users field in the project_user_select field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a possibility of one of the values being empty I would write it something like this:

```
// Get new value of field 1 or set value to null
if(!empty(get_field( 'project_manager' )) {
  $value1 = get_field( project_manager', $post_id, false );
} else {
  $value1 = '';
}
```

What this does is check if the field has entries, if it does it will assign the value to the variable `$value`. If the field does not have a value it will just declare the variable so when you try to add each of the `$values` to `$merge` it will still work because the variable has been declared.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work using array_merge.

```
function my_acf_save_post_31( $post_id ) {
// Get new value of field 1
$value1 = get_field( project_manager', $post_id, false );
// Get new value of field 2 
$value2 = get_field( 'architect', $post_id, false );
// Get new value of field 3 
$value3 = get_field( 'contractor', $post_id, false );

$merge = array_merge($value1,$value2,$value3);

update_field( 'project_user_select', $merge, $post_id );// update 
'other_field' with 'my_field' value
}
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post_31', 10 );
```

Comment: Good find, nicely done :)

Comment: What would be the best way to skip one of the arrays if it is empty?